# Is there a maximum length for Windows system sounds?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, wav, system-sounds

I want to set a song as my Windows 7 start-up sound. So I picked a song, trimmed it, and converted to a .WAV file.

I proceeded to add this file as a Windows log-in sound through `Personalize > Sounds`. But after I log off and back on, the song didn't play.

I tried these same steps with one of the default log-in sounds provided with Windows, and it worked just fine.

Why won't my song play? Is it because of the length of the audio file? And are there any work-arounds to make this work?

Comment: What length is the sound and how did you put it together (what program)?

Comment: its about 1 minute, and i used itunes to convert from MP3 to WAV

Comment: In general, the limit is imposed on the file size. But since we are working with just a single, uncompressed format (WAV), then length is proportional to the file size. I have no clue what the limit may be in this case.

Comment: Try making a shorter wav file using the same method to see if the length is an issue. You can probably cut down the length to a second or so within the program you used for the conversion. There are many features that could be used with in wav file that might not be supported.

Comment: i made a 30 second and that didnt work, now im going to try 2 second

Comment: the 2 second one worked so i guess there is a minimum...does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Suggestion: Since the "sample" (really a song) is long, I would delay the playback a few seconds after Windows loads. You want as little HD thrashing going on while everything is loading. Even if you use a SSD, you still want everything loaded as fast as possible. I usually turn off the on-load & shutoff sound for this reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case no one else finds a way to get around the maximum length, what I ended up doing was putting this batch file in the Startup folder of the start menu:

```
@echo off
start "My song.mp3"
```

and it worked fine for the most part

i also set the log on sound to none

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the limiting factor is the file size, rather than the length of the audio. Try saving the .WAV file with a lower bitrate. The default is usually CD-quality (44.1 kHz, 16-bit, stereo), so you could try lowering any or all of those parameters, depending on what options iTunes provides.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Windows Sounds dialog would load and recognize the .wav file but wouldn't play it, with this format:

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

I changed it to 22050 Hz with Audacity and it worked:

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 22050 Hz
```